# How does the cinderclaw gauntlet work with a monk?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

In Paizo's Age of Ashes: Hellknight Hill, there's a magical incendiary gauntlet called the *cinderclaw gauntlet*. If one of my players wants to equip this gauntlet on his monk, how does this gauntlet work with monk stances, monk unarmed attacks, and the Rain of Embers fire stance?

Cinderclaw gauntlet: https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=482

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**By default, they will not work with any Monk features.**

The Cinderclaw gauntlets are a Weapon (based on a spiked gauntlet), the same as a Longsword; they provide you with a way to make a new Strike against an opponent. In particular, they are NOT an "Unarmed" weapon like Fists are, and thus any bonuses a monk gets to their Unarmed Strikes do not apply to the gauntlets.

Since they are not a Monk weapon, even taking the [Monastic Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=434) feat will not help.

Rain of Embers only requires the user be unarmored, so the monk would be able to enter this stance with the gauntlets, but the stance also prevents the monk from making any Strikes other than fire talon Strikes, so you could not use the gauntlets (nor could you use any other unarmed Strikes!).

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to verify. Thank you.